# How to marshal function with out parameter to native code?

Tags: c#

I have delegate that is declared as:

```
        internal delegate bool readDelegate(out byte data);
```

At some point i want to get a function pointer to an instance of the delegate:

```
        readDelegate reader = (out byte data) => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Managed output! opening");
                if (stream.CanRead)
                {
                    data = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    data = 0;
                    return false;
                }
            };
```

which reads a singy byte from stream, if able.

But when i try to get a function pointer, like this:

```
IntPtr foo = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(reader);
```

I get an exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException was unhandled
  Message="0x80131515"
  StackTrace:
    в System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(Delegate d)
...
```

What is the reason? How should i change my code?

Answer (score 0):

What's the rest of the message of the exception? There should be a explanation of the error.

Anyway, I think this might work:

```
internal unsafe delegate bool readDelegate(byte* data);
```

Comment: Th rest of the message is continuation of stack trace where are the function marchaller is called in and the main function. Hardly relevant, i think.
Will try your variant.

Comment: Then all I can suggest is to put the functionality into a class that is ComVisible, and have the unmanaged code consume it as a COM class.